# PHP links not being re-done

Tags: php, html, dns, web, hosting

I was tasked with moving a website from one domain to another, so i copied the file of the original website which was domain.com and moved it to domain.net went ahead and renamed all files and all contents accordingly (just took out .com and put .net instead using ctrl+F) the website is up but my links somehow still point towards the old .com domain, where do i find these links in PHP, i'm sorry for the noob question, i'm really new to programming and only know JS, i just can't seem to find where those links are writen.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers but turned out cpanel has a very useful wildcard redirrect function, solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about what exactly you are asking but if i am you then rather changing each URL for my whole website I just redirect my old domain to new one by simple adding .htaccess file. For .htaccess i am referring you one link:

https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url

I hope it will help.